# xsl for ordering subnodes of xml

Tags: xml, xslt, sorting

Here is sample xml

```
<Data version="2.0">
   <Group>
        <Item>3</Item>
        <Item>1</Item>
        <Item>2</Item>
   </Group>
   <Group>
        <Item>7</Item>
        <Item>5</Item>
   </Group>
</Data>
```

And for ordering nodes in Group by Item value I tried to use the following xsl:

```
  <xsl:template match="/Data">

    <xsl:apply-templates select="Group">
      <xsl:sort select="Item" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>

  </xsl:template>
```

But get only values, even without sorting:

```
    3
    1
    2

    7
    5
```

So the questions are: 1. why sorting not work 2. How to keep all nodes and keep structure of xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Jim's answer is basically correct.

**However, applied to a slightly more realistic XML document, such as this**:

```
<Data version="2.0">
   <Group>
        <Item>3</Item>
        <Item>1</Item>
        <Item>10</Item>
        <Item>2</Item>
   </Group>
   <Group>
        <Item>7</Item>
        <Item>5</Item>
   </Group>
</Data>
```

**the result produced is clearly *not* what you want** (10 comes before 2 and 3):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Data version="2.0">

   <Group>
      <Item>1</Item>
      <Item>10</Item>
      <Item>2</Item>
      <Item>3</Item>
   </Group>

   <Group>
      <Item>5</Item>
      <Item>7</Item>
   </Group>

</Data>
```

**Here is a correct solution** (that is also slightly shorter):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Group">
  <Group>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="*">
    <xsl:sort data-type="number"/>
   </xsl:apply-templates>
  </Group>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the same XML document (above), the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<Data version="2.0">
   <Group>
      <Item>1</Item>
      <Item>2</Item>
      <Item>3</Item>
      <Item>10</Item>
   </Group>
   <Group>
      <Item>5</Item>
      <Item>7</Item>
   </Group>
</Data>
```

**Explanation**: Use of the `data-type` attribute of **[`<xsl:sort>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#sorting)** to specify that the sort keys value should be treated as number, not as (the default) string.

Answer (score 4):

This is what you want:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Group">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Item">
                <xsl:sort select="text()" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The first template is the "Identity Template" (Google it) which copies input to output unchanged.  Then for the Group node we copy it to the output (`<xsl:copy>`), copy its attributes, then copy the nested Item nodes after sorting them. They get copied because the inner `<xsl:apply-templates select="Item">` ends up using the Identity template since there's no more-specific template for Item nodes.

Note that if `Group` nodes can contain other stuff besides `Item` nodes, you'll have to make sure it gets copied as well.  The template above would discard them.